# SSRS Replace Function in Textbox Expression

Tags: replace, ssrs-2008-r2

I have an Expression in a Textbox as below...

```
=First(Replace(Fields!Analyst.Value, "eu\", ""), "DataSet")
```

I want the "eu\" text removed from the value.

The above does not give any error but does not remove the text.

What do I need to do for this to work? I just right-clicked on the Textbox and clicked Expression and added in that line of code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this expression:

=Replace(Fields!Analyst.Value, "eu\", "")